# SQL: Return most recent actions, but limit to 10 results

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit

I have a table with actions performed by actors and want to return 10 of the most recent actions. I want actors to be unique within this list.  'created' is a time/date stamp. How can I do this most efficiently?  I came up with the following query, which works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activities a
JOIN 
(SELECT actor, MAX(created) created 
 FROM activities 
 WHERE comment_type <> 'profile.status' 
 GROUP BY actor) t ON (a.actor = t.actor AND a.created = t.created) LIMIT 10
```

The table could eventually be quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the limit 10 inside the subquery.
Other than that it looks OK

```
SELECT * FROM activities a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
              actor
              , MAX(created) created 
            FROM activities 
            WHERE comment_type <> 'profile.status' 
            GROUP BY actor
            LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t
      ON (a.actor = t.actor AND a.created = t.created) LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you only need the actor you can do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor -- and any other actor specific columns that are unique to the actor
FROM activities 
WHERE comment_type <> 'profile.status'
ORDER BY Created DESC
LIMIT 10
```